# My Database Tables With Collation "In Use" Can't be Loaded

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have a problem with my table in my server.

Few times ago, my projects were fine. But, when I'm accessing the projects, most of them get error. It turns out that, the error was caused by my server. I checked the tables, turn out all the tables collation was changed from "utf8_unicode_ci" to "in use", consecutively the tables can not be browsed or exported because the records have missed.

How can I repair those tables? need help.....
thx...

Answer (score 0):

Could this be due to the bug http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=8235 in MySQL 4.1.9? What version and storage engines are you using?

Did you change, delete or alter the table data because of this? If so, you'll have to restore from backups — if you have any.

If the data hasn't been changed, it is only failing on SELECTs because of unexpected collation settings, you could try changing the collation settings so your SELECT queries work as expected. You can set it permanently on the tables, via your [connection](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-connection.html), or in each SQL statement specially. See the [MySQL documentation 9.1.7.2. Using COLLATE in SQL Statements](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-collate.html). (Though I'm not sure if this solution will fix the problem.)